# Error when installing OpenCV 3 - unable to locate package python3-opencv

Tags: windows, python, opencv

```
julham@DESKTOP-JTEILQT:~$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-opencv
```